SPSS Computing Sleep Duration
I want to compute the sleep duration of my participants. As items I have the bed time and the time they got out of bed (some went to bed before 00:00 and some after). Format is hhmmss.
To compute the sleeping Time I already found this code:
DATA LIST FREE / outofbed bedtime (2TIME5).
BEGIN DATA
08:00 22:00
06:00 21:00
05:30 20:30
21:45 07:00
END DATA.

DO IF outofbed < bedtime.
  COMPUTE sleepDur = 24 - CTIME.HOURS(bedtime-outofbed).
ELSE.
  COMPUTE sleepDur = CTIME.HOURS(outofbed-bedtime).
END IF.
EXECUTE.

Problem is: Some went to bed at p.e. 00:45:00 and woke up at 09:30:00. The sleep time I got is 8:75 (instead of 8:45). What can I do differently to get the right answers?
(sorry, English is not my first language)

Welcome to Stack-Overflow! +1 for the good question with the reproducible example. The explanation is simple though - the variable you computed sleepDur is a numerical value which gives the answer as the number of hours. Note that the value you get is not 8:75 but 8.75 as in eight hours and three quarters...

Thanks for the answer. I was so tired yesterday hahah. Now in the morning it seems so obvious
